# PyCharm: Switch from terminal to source code with keystrokes

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I switch from the terminal window (inside PyCharm) to the Python-Code again?

I tried `CTRL-TAB` but the default action of this switcher pop-up window is to go the second last Python file.

I tried "Navigate | Last Edit Location." ([navigation to recent file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/navigating-to-recent-file.html) but the input cursor stays in the terminal :-(

The only solution I found was `CTRL-TAB-Up`.  Is there no solution without a pop-up window?

BTW, this is a follow-up question to this question: [PyCharm: Switch between Code and Run/Terminal with CapsLock-u and CapsLock-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436719/pycharm-switch-between-code-and-run-terminal-with-capslock-u-and-capslock-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello again @guettli there is a solution with the popup window of the switcher, but it is still macro record-able, so it will fit in your previous question:

When you are editing a file and the move to the terminal, when you hit: **Ctrl+Tab, let go of Tab and hit PageUp** you will switch to the last selected open tab.

Record this as your macro and have fun :)

Comment: I ask myself if I am on the right track. The CapsLock-n question was special. That's ok to record a macro for this. But here I wonder why nobody else want to use the keyboard to navigate back to the source code. I don't like to do strange stuff. If more people would like to navigate back to source code via keyboard, then there would be a short-cut.

Comment: Well, the way I see it, if something makes **you** productive, then it is the right thing to use!

Comment: Use Rstudio... and then you can just use ctrl + 1 and ctrl + 2. Use reticulate and you can make python chunks.