# PyCharm Auto Pull when Creating Git Branch

Tags: pycharm

Does anyone know if there is a way to automatically perform a pull on a git branch before you create a local git branch within PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an official way as of the moment (PyCharm 2016.3) but I can suggest a similar work-around that worked successfully in another case: [PyCharm: Switch between Code and Run/Terminal with CapsLock-u and CapsLock-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436719/pycharm-switch-between-code-and-run-terminal-with-capslock-u-and-capslock-n?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Record a macro with the instruction given in the linked answer that:

1. Pulls from the current branch (Ctrl + T and then hit Enter)
2. Hit Alt+S (opens the VCS dropdown menu from the tool bar)
3. Hit Alt+G (selects the Git on this dropdown and opens an expansion box)
4. Hit Alt+B (opens the *brances* selection menu)
5. Hit Enter (on the above mentioned selection menu the first choice is the *"+ New Branch"*)
6. Stop recording the macro, give it a name and assign it a hot key if you want from the Settings > Keymap.

Now you have a macro that when you hit it, pulls from the current branch and starts the creation of a new branch in which you only have to enter the name of the new branch!

**Note:** This macro is suggested under the assumption that you are creating a new branch on Git and on Linux. Your setting maybe different so you will have to adjust the process!

Good luck :)